# RegEx How to avoid automatically closing HTML tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

HTML:

```
<pre class="html">
   List<String> list = Arrays.asList(str);
</pre>
```

JS:

```
var symbols = /(<|>|{|})/gi;

$('.html').each(function() {
   var abc =  $(this).html().replace(symbols, "<span class='blue'>$1</span>");
$(this).html(abc);
}
```

Output: (I am able to change the color of <,>)

```
List<string> list = Arrays.asList(str);
</string>
```

Its automatically appending

```
 </string> at the end
```

and changing String to string (First letter capital to small)

Can anybody please help me how to fix this issue.

Comment: Use jQuery's `text()` instead

Comment: If I use text() the output is List list = Arrays.asList(str); its hiding <String> totally

Comment: Set this up in jsFiddle, and reproduce the problem there

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gew41fo2/

Comment: Thanks for putting in the fiddle Adeneo...is there a way to achieve this without changing &lt; or &gt;

Comment: Probably not, as then it's invalid HTML

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this:

```
<pre class="html">
   List<String> list = Arrays.asList(str);
</pre>
```

Escape your brackets:

```
<pre class="html">
   List&lt;String&gt; list = Arrays.asList(str);
</pre>
```

---

An alternative way would be to put your code in a script tag to avoid it being interpreted as an HTML tag:

```
<script type="template" id="code">
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(str);
</script>
<div id="output"></div>

var symbols = /(<|>|{|})/gi;

var code = document.getElementById("code").textContent;
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = code.replace(symbols, "<span class='blue'>$1</span>");
```

The downside is that all your leading whitespaces would be gone.

Comment: I cannot escape Derek..this is only the sample..I have lot of < > in my code..so I don't want to mess up all the code..and trying for some alternative...

Comment: Thanks for the alternative Derek, but I should not put in <script>... that should be only in <pre> which can preserve line breaks

Comment: @John Well there is no other way of doing this without escaping except putting your code in a file on your server and retrieving it through AJAX. You are basically asking how to put double quotes in strings without escaping them.